# scrolling a circular layout collection view

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that has a circular layout. How can I rotate the cells or add scroll to the layout. I looked into iCarousel. But want to do it myself.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide some code of the problem you are having? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the specific problem you are having.

Comment: I have a circular collection view like the one described in this blog http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/fixing-circlelayout/ . I want to rotate/scroll the cells up and down when user scrolls the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an custom UICollectionviewLayout, which layout's the collection view cells in an circular layout. It can be configured to show an particular.

In your case you would be needing an 180 - 0 degrees.

You can fork and understand the code.

https://github.com/DoddaSrinivasan/DSCircularCollectionView